# problema con checkboxs icheck-boostrap

Tags: laravel, bootstrap, checkbox

estoy ingresando con un foreach N cantidad de checkbox en un modal, pero al momento de seleccionar cualquier checkbox solo me selecciona el primero, alguien sabe como arreglar ese tema, por lo que veo es el tema del id y for de mi input y label, les adjunto código:

```html
<div class="form">
  @foreach ($checkPermisos as $chPermisos)
  
  <div class="icheck-material-red">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form" id="permissions" name="permission[]" value="{{$chPermisos->id}}">
    <label for="permissions">{{$chPermisos->descripcion}}</label>
  </div>
  
  @endforeach
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No te va a funcionar si le pones la misma id a todas las etiquetas <input>. Para que necesitas la id? Si no la vas a usar solo quitale el atributo id

Comment: al parecer ichek ocupa los atributos id y for para realizar el chek en el cuadro, si igual lo pensé, pero al sacarles el id y for, no me selecciona ningún checkbox

Comment: Podes usar. $loop->iteration  para crear los atributos id y for como arrays

Comment: estaba revisando algo de eso, pero no entiendo como seria ya que no hya ejemplos con id :c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar la variable [$loop](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#the-loop-variable) con la propiedad `iteration` para generar los atributos `id` y `for` de las etiquetas como arrays:

```
<div class="form">
  @foreach ($checkPermisos as $chPermisos)

  <div class="icheck-material-red">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form" id="permissions[{{ $loop->iteration }}]" name="permission[]" value="{{$chPermisos->id}}">
    <label for="permissions[{{ $loop->iteration }}]">{{$chPermisos->descripcion}}</label>
  </div>

  @endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias amigo!!! solucionado, no concia esas variables

Comment: Ok, ahí te pasé el link a la documentación en la respuesta. Yo no conocía ese plugin icheck, hice una búsqueda y me encontré con [esta](https://github.com/fronteed/icheck), que supongo que es la que estás usando

Comment: es una librería de bootstrap, si la quieres es esta [icheck](https://www.npmjs.com/package/icheck-bootstrap)

Comment: Genial, gracias. Me quedaba esa duda. Recuerda que cuando usas una librería para la que S. Overflow no tiene etiqueta, es mejor incluir el link a la documentación/readme en la pregunta para que sepamos a que te refieres. Saludos.

Comment: aaa ya muchas gracias por la recomendación! saludos